# Stored Procedure to delete records in a table from values in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am having table, `table A` and `table B,C,D etc`. `table A` has three columns namely `id`,`date` and `tracker`.

From `table A` I have to pick rows which has data more than 30 days from `date` column which is of datatype `date`. From the obtained result I have to `DELETE` records in `table B,C,D etc` based on the `id` and `tracker`(tracker column's data will provide the target tables name) from `table A`. For example `id` = `3` from `table A` will remove the records of `id` = `3` from `table B,C,D etc` provided by `tracker` column.

ID will be the same in both the tables. Table B,C,D etc will have many other columns to it.

Comment: Consumable sample data, expected results, *and* your attempts will help us help you. Also tables don't have "records", they have rows and columns.

Comment: I don't think you need a procedure for this. Just a plain old DELETE statement will cover it. Please share sample data and desired results so we can help more.

Comment: This is not specifically anything to do with a stored procedure, it's just a query; Write your query to identify the target records, probably using `exists`, once it returns the correct rows convert it into a delete statement.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong mention. The column 'tracker' data will be the table's  name from which the ID has to be removed. Can we pass the table name as parameter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, beeing very simplistic here but

```
DELETE FROM [Table B]
WHERE
    [Table B].[id] IN (SELECT [Table A].[id] AS [innerID]
                       WHERE [Table A].[date] < DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE()));
```

It would basically delete all records from Table B where those records have identical id values on Table A and the date column is older than 30 days from today

For the other tables just repeat the process; you can also create a temporary table variable to store that select and use it in the next queries, like this:

```
DECLARE @ids TABLE(id INT);
INSERT INTO @ids(id)
  SELECT [Table A].[id] AS [innerID]
  WHERE [Table A].[date] < DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE());
DELETE FROM [Table B] WHERE [Table B].[id] IN (SELECT id FROM @ids);
DELETE FROM [Table C] WHERE [Table C].[id] IN (SELECT id FROM @ids);
DELETE FROM [Table D] WHERE [Table D].[id] IN (SELECT id FROM @ids);
```

From your edit, "tracker column's data will provide the target tables name" you'll have to do something like this (just hinting it, haven't checked all the syntax):

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = '' --put the entire query here (all the declarations, and run)
EXEC(@query)
```

That's very dangerous to do

Comment: Thank you for guiding me the path. I am still not with a solution but now clear with how to proceed on this. I will sure figure that out and get back here.